# Site on django doesn't load static

Tags: django, django-staticfiles, django-bootstrap3

My site on django doesn't load static files

base.html:

```
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css' %}">
<script src="{% static 'jquery/dist/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
```

files:

[image]

from terminal:

```
[13/Mar/2022 03:36:26] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 24975
[13/Mar/2022 03:36:26] "GET /static/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1758
[13/Mar/2022 03:36:26] "GET /static/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1751
[13/Mar/2022 03:36:26] "GET /static/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1760
[13/Mar/2022 03:36:26] "GET /media/cache/77/1c/771c04f6935d264617dd3dec309a41d0.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 1773
```

What could be be the reason of this?

Comment: Did you define **STATIC_URL** and **STATICFILES_DIRS** in settings? if not check this [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/)

Comment: yes.

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / 'assets'
]

STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'static

Comment: Please add more information like do you use runserver? Are you running it with debug=true? Content of urls.py? Your settings.py?

Comment: @Razenstein  python3 manage.py collectstatic  436 static files copied to '/home/maskalev/Dev/hw05_final/static'.  But I have 436 messages like this:  Found another file with the destination path 'debug_toolbar/js/redirect.js'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.  But I'm sure that static directory was empty!  No, debug=false.  In case debug=true static is ok.  Why?

Comment: With debug= false django will not serve static files. That is intended behavior. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments:

> With debug= false django will not serve static files. That is intended behavior. > See docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files

Thanks to *@Razenstein* for answer!

Answer (score 0):

Alxender, you should write these link and scripts in the base.html file and whenever you want static in a file write {% load static %} each time in each file.
You should also run this code in the terminal before running the server

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

You should also check if you have set these settings in project/settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (str(BASE_DIR.joinpath('static')),)
STATIC_ROOT = str(BASE_DIR.joinpath('staticfiles')) 
STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
 "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder",
 "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder",
   ]
```

Comment: vijay, i wrote html code from base.html (now i checked it on my question). and i ran collectstatic of course.